# Creating a VS solution to install Python and related libraries

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio

I have a application running on Python that I need to deploy on multiple machines. I do not want the installers to download Python, install libraries and then be able to run the application.

I have written some code in C# to enable downloading and installation of Python. While this part has been taken care of I am trying to install libraries by calling CMD.exe from my code. This is not calling the pip method and my libraries are not getting installed.

Here is the code:

```cs
public void libraries() {
    Console.WriteLine("Staring library download");
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C pip install scikit-image");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Is there a reason we cannot call `pip` from cmd in this way or is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: How do you use pip without a python interpreter as pip is written in python?

Comment: @Bailey Kocin: `pip` is an `.exe` file in the `C:\python3\scripts` directory in modern versions of Python.

Comment: But it's still written in python and unless it's bundled with an interpreter you still need one to run it no?

Comment: @BaileyKocin: Not sure, but you may be correct (never tried it on a system that didn't have Python installed and am not sure why you would even need it on one that didn't).

Comment: Sourabh: Can you run `pip` from cmd manually? If not, you'll have to either add the directory it is in to your `PATH` environment variable, or explicitly give the complete path to the exe in what you pass `Start()`.

Comment: @BaileyKocin I do have Python installed with the same program in a method that’s executed before this method. I was able to verify the Python installation separately as well. So not sure why pip doesn’t work as expected

Comment: @martineau yes I can run pip manually and install the packages I need.

Comment: How, exactly, is it not working as expected? What happens? Are there error messages?

Comment: well there is message on cmd but it disappears quickly, let me try to see if I can make the console stay for a while to see the exact error.

Comment: any idea people? Still working on this, made some code changes to use waitforExit method for process : `Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Python36\python-3.6.3-amd64.exe";
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();` but the next block executes before Python is done instaling.